# how to convert QBytearray to QString?

Tags: qt, qstring, qbytearray

now I have a QByteArray object, I need to convert it to QString and print the content in HEX format. But I don't find correct method.

```
`QByteArray serial; 
serial.resize(4);
serial[0] = 0xA0;
serial[1] = 0x01;
serial[2] = 0x05;
serial[3] = 0xA6;`
```

QString str = "how to convert serial to QString"

convert "serial" object to QString object and the print format is "0xA0 0x01 0x05 0xA6"

Comment: Just use the appropriate [`QString` constructor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstring.html#QString-9).

Comment: See [QByteArray::toHex()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qbytearray.html#toHex) on how to display the values of the QByteArray as hexadecimal string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this one-liner solution will be useful:

```
auto str = QString("0x%1").arg(QString(serial.toHex(':').toUpper())).replace(":"," 0x");
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).